# Promises in recursive algorithms not working - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

I am working on controller in node.js for inserting data into database. The data I want to put into db are multilevel JSON. I would like to use recursive function that unwrapp the arrays inside json and put them in different tables in db. The function look like this:

```
function LoopThroughObject(obiekt,masterKey,relation){
if(!relation) var undef = true
for(key in obiekt){
    if(obiekt[key].constructor === Array){
        LoopThroughObject(obiekt[key],key,relation)
    } else if(obiekt[key].constructor === Object){
        var pp
        (function(v1,v2){       
           pp = db.InsertData(masterKey,output)
            when(pp,function(data){         
                    LoopThroughObject(v1,v2,data.insertId)
                }, function(err){     
                }) 
            p.push(pp) 
        })(obiekt[key],masterKey)
        }     
    if(undef) relation = ''  
}    
}
```

The function  works properly with the exception to promises. Here is the code I am executing:

```
var input =  {projectsData:
            [{  name:'test_project',
                desc:'test description',
                date_start:'21.01.2017',
                date_end:'25.01.2017',
                date_ddl:'24.01.2017',
                tagsData:[{tag:10},{tag:2},{tag:3},{tag:4},{tag:5}],
                usersCoData:[{user:20,role:1},
                             {user:1,role:2},
                             {user:3,role:2}
                            ]
            }]
        }

var when = require("promised-io/promise").when  

LoopThroughObject(input,'','')

group = require("promised-io/promise").all(p);

group.then(function(){
   console.log('Success')
},function(){
    console.log('Fail')
});
```

Now, the problem I have is with promises. After executing the script the function promises.all always return success. Even though there is an intentional error in the input json. If I dump it into the console it looks like the promises.all is fired before the error is thrown. So I guess this is some kind of problem with recursive pattern but not sure how to solve it. Please help!

**EDIT**
I have done a little diging in order to familiarize myself better with the recursive promises. I created the following example (db modlue is already using promises), however still can't make it work:

```
function loopviarecursive(i){
var q = new Deferred();
if(i<10){
    db.InsertData('projects',{  
project_name:'test_project'}).then(function(data){
        i++
        q = loopviarecursive(i)
        console.log('Iteration  '+i)
    }, function(err){
        console.log('Fail to insert')
        q.reject(err)
    })
}else {
    q.resolve()
}
return q.promise
}

var d = loopviarecursive(0)
when(d,function(){console.log('sucess')},function(){console.log('fail')})
```

Any advices about how to make it work are most welcome :)

Comment: Promises don't magically know what you want ... your LoopThroughObject code is fundamentally flawed on a number of levels - for one thing, you run the `.all(p)` before any asynchronous code has even had a chance to run, and "populate" `p` (which is undeclared, so how does `p.push` even work!!!)

Comment: `if(!relation) var undef = true` is basically `var undef = !relation`

Comment: ok, thanks for input. So I should modify the function so that it calls itself after first has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't call LoopThroughObject inside a Promise neither does LoopThroughObject return a promise and you haven't defined p which should be an array of promises (which wouldn't make sense, since you only have one Promise).

I guess in your case you don't need a Promise, because you don't load data asynchronous, do you?

Maybe [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) would help you find out how and when to use Promises.

I hope that would help :)

Comment: p should be defined, probably I didn't copy it here. As for loading data asynchronusly, I am doing it with each call for function. So that the same levels of json can be inserted pararelly

Comment: Ok, but when is you "end"-state reached? Because right now you are calling LoopThroughObject outside of a Promise and you are not returning a Promise as well to then add a `.then` callback

Comment: @lumio - I would venture that `db.InsertData(masterKey,output)` may return a promise, or is, at the very least, asyncrhonous

Comment: actually I am calling it in the promise of db insert (async) thats way my understanding is that it should wait untill all the promises ar reslved

Comment: Ah! But could it be that there is a dot missing before the when statement

Comment: hi, I updated my question with simple example of what I need to achieve